# Physical examples where changing the order of limits yields wrong result

Tags: education

In mathematics it is generally not allowed to change order of [limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence). For example it is not always true for a sequence of functions $f_n$, that $\int_a^b \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n(x) \right) dx = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\int_a^b f_n(x) dx\right)$. (Note that series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\ldots$ and the integral $\int_a^b \ldots dx$ are mathematically defined via limits of sequences).

In my experience it happens a lot in physics lectures, that limits are changed in their order without any additional comment (such as mentioning [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) or [uniform convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#To_integrability)). It also seems to me that there are not many examples relevant for physics where changing the order of limits yield wrong results.

I'm looking for good physical examples showing to students that one has to be careful when he changes the order of limits. So for which physical example the order of the limits is important and you get a wrong result, when you change it?

Comment: You're not changing the limits. You're changing the order of operators which is only valid for linear operators (or commuting operators).

Comment: In physics lectures, you do ***not*** change the limits so as to get the wrong results because you don't actually want to present the wrong result to the class.

Comment: @tpg2114 The post specifically mentions that both operators are defined via limits. Anyway, you should find plenty of examples in statistical mechanics: In particular you'll see a lot of limits where the ratio has to be constant (both the size of a system and the number of particles it contains has to go to infinity, yet their ratio, density, has to remain constant)

Comment: @alarge But the limits aren't changing -- OP isn't saying that instead of the integral from $a$ to $b$ it's now $a$ to $c \neq b$. That would be changing the limits. Instead, the question is about changing the *order* of the operators (or order of the limits) which is not the same as changing the limits.

Comment: @tpg2114: By "changing the limit" I mean "changing the order of the limits" ;-) I will correct this mistake...

Comment: This question (v2) seems like a list question.

Comment: This appears to be too broad of a question because there is not really any wrong answer.

Comment: One such situation [came up in chat recently](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/71/2015/02/07). DanielSank described an LC circuit ladder, where any finite segment has an imaginary impedance, but the whole thing seems to have a real impedance. The resolution is that there is another limit involved in calculating these quantities, and the order of limits (response time, number of segments) is tacitly switched between the two cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The low-frequency ($\omega\rightarrow 0$), long-wavelength ($q\rightarrow 0$) conductivity of an electron gas in the random phase approximation depends on the order in which those two limits are taken.

Intuitively, if you take the $\omega\rightarrow 0$ limit first, you're talking about a **static**, long-wavelength potential to which the electrons adjust, so the conductivity is imaginary (non-dissapative).  If you take the $q\rightarrow 0$ limit first, you're talking about a **uniform**, slowly varying field applied to the gas, so you get a current (real conductivity).  See page 27 of [these notes](http://young.physics.ucsc.edu/232/rpa2.pdf) for a discussion.

Basically, you order the limits one way to learn about Thomas-Fermi screening, and the other way to learn about DC currents.  Changing the limits here is not "wrong" *per se*, but it may get you an answer to a question you didn't ask!

Answer (score 2):

For example, in statistical mechanics, you get different results for systems with spontaneous symmetry breaking, say, for a ferromagnetic, depending  on whether you first take the limit $N\rightarrow\infty$ or $H\rightarrow 0$ when calculating average magnetization (http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Quasi-averages,_method_of ).